# Where can I find NPC statistics for dragonborn and half elves?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, npc

I swear I've seen it in the Monster Manual, but I can't seem to find it anymore. Where can I find statistics for dragonborn and half elf NPCs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the only mention in the Monster Manual of NPCs with a specific race is the following:

> ***Racial Traits.***
>   You can add racial traits to an NPC.
>   For example, a halfling priest might have a speed of 25
>   feet and the Lucky trait. Adding racial traits to an NPC
>   doesn’t alter its challenge rating. For more on racial
>   traits, see the
>   Player’s Handbook
>   or the D&D player’s
>   basic rules.

So basically, if you want a dragonborn NPC, you should give them a breath weapon and damage resistance, just like a dragonborn PC. For half-elves, you would give them Fey Ancestry, Darkvision, and 2 skill proficiencies. Obviously in both cases you would also describe them with an appearance appropriate to their race.

You might have been thinking of half-dragon NPCs rather than dragonborn - half-dragons have a very well defined template which you add to an NPC to make it a half-dragon. (It's under H for half-dragon.) I'm not sure what you could have been thinking of for half-elves, though.

Comment: I might be thinking back to the 4e MM

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the Dungeon Masters Guide. On page 282 it explains the creation of NPC's from scratch. It has a list of Racial features the NPC could have.

> Dragonborn* +2 Str, + 1 Cha Breath Weapon (use challenge rating instead of level to determine damage), Damage Resistance, Draconic Ancestry; speaks Common and Draconic
>
> *See the Player 's Handbook for descriptions of this race's features , none of which alter the NPC's challenge rating.

Another place to look is Appendix B from the Monster Manual (page 342), It contains stat blocks of "Medium humanoid (any race), any alignment"